# Php.$_FILE is not working .I cant find a solution

Tags: php

This is a php code.Its not working.Is storing in db name of image,not image.
i serached for this problem but i cant find a solution.i tried file_get_contents() but doesnt work.I dont if is a problem with server or code.

```
<?php
    $msg="";
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        session_start();

        $target_dir="uploads/";
        $target_file=$target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

        include 'dbh.php';

        $image=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
        $image_tmp=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
        $id=$_SESSION['id'];
        $sql="UPDATE user SET image='$image' WHERE id='$id'";
        mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or Die("ERROR:" .mysqli_error($conn));

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $target_file)){
            $msg="Image uploaded successfully";
        }
        else{
            $msg="There was a problem uploading image";
        }

    }

    ?>




<form action="user_photo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="iframe">
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ngarko Foto">
      </form>
```

Comment: Do you really want to store the image into the database, not just the name of the file in the `uploads` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_get_contents` should work. But the image data is binary, so you can't just substitute it into the SQL. You should use a prepared statement.

```
$image = file_get_contents($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
$sql = "UPDATE user SET image = ? WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "bi", $image, $_SESSION['id']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_error("ERROR:" .$conn));
```

Comment: What part of it don't you understand? Maybe you should read a tutorial on prepared statements.

Comment: mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "bi", $image, $_SESSION['id']); i don't understand this function. ''bi"-what is that ?   Thanks @Barmar

Comment: hey @Barmar ,is not working now code that u give me.I dont know why.it worked first time that i use.

Comment: @ArmandRexhmati Did you try reading the documentation? It explains what `bi` is. `b` stands for `blob`, `i` stands for `integer`.